# EntityState Of Inherited Properties Remains Unchanged

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an entity that inherits from a base class, when I update a the inherited property, the `EntityState` is unchanged

```cs
public abstract class BaseEntity
    {
        public DateTime? DeletedDateTime { get; set; }
        public string DeletedByApplicationUserID { get; set; }
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    }

public class Incident : BaseEntity
    {
        public string IncidentId { get; set; }
        //..other props
    }


public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        AddTimeStamps();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

private void AddTimeStamps()
    {
        var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.Entity is BaseEntity && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified || x.State == EntityState.Deleted));
        foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                //prevent default .remove behavior 
                if(entity.State == EntityState.Deleted)
                {
                    ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).Deleted = true;
                    entity.State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
                //user used the delete method of the base entity
                if (((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).Deleted)
                {
                    ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).DeletedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                    ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).DeletedByApplicationUserID = currentUserId;
                }
            }
    }
```

When I call the following function, the deleted is not set as true

```
public OtherMethod(string incidentId)
        {
            using (ApplicationDbContext db = dbContextWrapper.DbContext())
            {

                var incident = db.Incidents.Where(x => x.IncidentId == incidentId).FirstOrDefault();
                if (incident != null)
                {
                    db.Entry(incident).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;//who knows why i have to do this
                    incident.Delete();  
                    db.SaveChanges();                

                }
            }
        }
```

Setting the state manually does work, if possible i would like to avoid doing so.

not doing this: `db.Entry(incident).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;` , makes the tracker ignore the deleted change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the property  was purposely ignored as here :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Incident>().Map(m => m.Requires("Deleted").HasValue(false))
                .Ignore(m => m.Deleted);
```